# How to style each thumb independently when material ui slider have multiple thumbs?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, slider

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Slider from '@material-ui/core/Slider';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Tooltip from '@material-ui/core/Tooltip';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    width: 300 + theme.spacing(3) * 2,
  },
  margin: {
    height: theme.spacing(3),
  },
}));

const AirbnbSlider = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: '#3a8589',
    height: 3,
    padding: '13px 0',
  },
  thumb: {
    height: 27,
    width: 27,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    border: '1px solid currentColor',
    marginTop: -12,
    marginLeft: -13,
    boxShadow: '#ebebeb 0 2px 2px',
    '&:focus, &:hover, &$active': {
      boxShadow: '#ccc 0 2px 3px 1px',
    },
    '& .bar': {
      // display: inline-block !important;
      height: 9,
      width: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'currentColor',
      marginLeft: 1,
      marginRight: 1,
    },
  },
  active: {},
  track: {
    height: 3,
  },
  rail: {
    color: '#d8d8d8',
    opacity: 1,
    height: 3,
  },
})(Slider);

function AirbnbThumbComponent(props) {
  return (
    <span {...props}>
      <span className="bar" />
      <span className="bar" />
      <span className="bar" />
    </span>
  );
}

export default function CustomizedSlider() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Typography gutterBottom>Airbnb</Typography>
      <AirbnbSlider
        ThumbComponent={AirbnbThumbComponent}
        getAriaLabel={(index) => (index === 0 ? 'Minimum price' : 'Maximum price')}
        defaultValue={[20, 40]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Material-UI [passes a `data-index` prop](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v5.0.0-beta.5/packages/material-ui-unstyled/src/SliderUnstyled/SliderUnstyled.js#L748) to the thumb which will be `0` for the first thumb and `1` for the second. You can leverage this prop to add an additional class to the thumb which you can then use in your styles:

```
function AirbnbThumbComponent(props) {
  const { children, className, ...other } = props;
  const extraClassName =
    other["data-index"] === 0 ? "first-thumb" : "second-thumb";
  return (
    <SliderThumb {...other} className={clsx(className, extraClassName)}>
      {children}
      <span className="airbnb-bar" />
      <span className="airbnb-bar" />
      <span className="airbnb-bar" />
    </SliderThumb>
  );
}
```

Below is a full working example. This example uses v5 and the `styled` function, but the same approach is doable with v4 using `withStyles`.

This produces the following look:

[image: slider with different thumbs]

```
import * as React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Slider, { SliderThumb } from "@material-ui/core/Slider";
import { styled } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import clsx from "clsx";

const AirbnbSlider = styled(Slider)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: "#3a8589",
  height: 3,
  padding: "13px 0",
  "& .MuiSlider-thumb": {
    height: 27,
    width: 27,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    border: "1px solid currentColor",
    "&.second-thumb": {
      border: "2px dashed purple"
    },
    "&:hover": {
      boxShadow: "0 0 0 8px rgba(58, 133, 137, 0.16)"
    },
    "& .airbnb-bar": {
      height: 9,
      width: 1,
      marginLeft: 1,
      marginRight: 1
    },
    "&.first-thumb .airbnb-bar": {
      backgroundColor: "red"
    },
    "&.second-thumb .airbnb-bar": {
      backgroundColor: "currentColor"
    }
  },
  "& .MuiSlider-track": {
    height: 3
  },
  "& .MuiSlider-rail": {
    color: theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? "#bfbfbf" : "#d8d8d8",
    opacity: theme.palette.mode === "dark" ? undefined : 1,
    height: 3
  }
}));

function AirbnbThumbComponent(props) {
  const { children, className, ...other } = props;
  const extraClassName =
    other["data-index"] === 0 ? "first-thumb" : "second-thumb";
  return (
    <SliderThumb {...other} className={clsx(className, extraClassName)}>
      {children}
      <span className="airbnb-bar" />
      <span className="airbnb-bar" />
      <span className="airbnb-bar" />
    </SliderThumb>
  );
}

AirbnbThumbComponent.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node
};

export default function CustomizedSlider() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: 320 }}>
      <Typography gutterBottom>Airbnb</Typography>
      <AirbnbSlider
        components={{ Thumb: AirbnbThumbComponent }}
        getAriaLabel={(index) =>
          index === 0 ? "Minimum price" : "Maximum price"
        }
        defaultValue={[20, 40]}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit CustomizedSlider different thumbs]